# Setting default properties of custom control

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, custom-component

I've written a control descended from TCustomEdit but am having trouble changing the default size of the component from that defined in StdCtrls (i.e. width=121, height=21).

So in Create I have:

```
inherited Create(AOwner);
width:=40;
height:=20;
```

But when the control is placed on the form it is drawn with the default width and height for TCustomEdit. I've reduced the test case to a simple component that merely has the constructor above and nothing else. I've also tried setting `autosize:=false` in the constructor but no joy.

From searching around I think I'm doing the right thing but plainly it's not working. How to I get the behaviour I'm after?

Comment: Is your constructor called? Have you marked it as `override`?

Comment: Always solve all compiler hints, warnings and errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That works for me (XE2). Make sure your constructor is marked `override` so that it is actually called:

```
constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
```

This is necessary because `TComponent` has a virtual constructor.

Comment: Also don't forget to set the default value of published properties to the same value. property Width default 40; This helps the form streamer and helps you if you want to change the default in the future.

Comment: @Lars, I don't think so. The `default` doesn't set the property value; this is done in constructor. About helping to change the value in future; from the designer point of view it's fine because `Object Inspector` highlights the value different from the `default` one as bold and without bold, if the entered value equals to the `default` one. From the component developer's point of view you can easily forget to change the `default` and the real default property value in constructor.

Comment: @Lars Height and Width are not published with default values and so they are always persisted to the .dfm file.

Comment: @TLama You are right that setting the default on a published property does not change it's value. I haven't claimed otherwise.

Comment: @David Didn't knew that. Then let it be a suggestion for the other published properties.

Comment: @David: `Height` and `Width` do not have an explicit default value declared in `TControl`, so they have an implicit default of zero. Integer properties are only streamed if they are different than their default value. If you change the default values in a derived constructor, the property declarations need to be updated in the derived class to match.

Comment: @Remy No, I'm afraid you've got that wrong. Because they are published with no default being specified, they are always streamed. Check this yourself with a simple package containing a component with a single integer property. I just did!

Comment: @David: I have been writing custom components for years. Integer properties with no `default` assigned are treated as `default=0` by the compiler, and thus are not streamed when their value is `0` unless they have a `nodefault` clause assigned. This is documented behavior, and common knowledge amongst component writers.

Comment: @remy I just implemented a component with an integer property. Published like this: `property test:integer read ftest write ftest;` and the value 0 was streamed. I can't see where I'm going wrong.